# Read multiple files from S3 and process with Apache Spark

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am trying to get a collection of files according to LastModifiedDate from S3

```
    List <String>  FileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest() 
                    .withBucketName(s3_bucket) 
                    .withPrefix(logs_dir);

```
        ObjectListing objectListing; 


        do { 
            objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest); 
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : 
                    objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) { 

                if ((objectSummary.getLastModified().compareTo(dayBefore) > 0)  && (objectSummary.getLastModified().compareTo(dayAfter) <1) && objectSummary.getKey().contains(".log")) 
                    FileNames.add(objectSummary.getKey()); 
            } 
            listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker()); 
        } while (objectListing.isTruncated());
```

I would like to process these files using Spark

I understand that sc.textFile reads a single text file in spark. But in my case the List has the paths of all the files I want to read. Is there any way to read all these files that are part of the List?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to map over the list of filenames with sc.textfile and then union the resulting RDDs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a list and then create a concat string out of it and then use this as part of textfile

```
String concatName= "";
    for(String fName : FileNames) {
       if(FileNames.indexOf(fName) == (FileNames.size() -1)) {
          concatName+= "s3n://" + s3_bucket + "/" + fName;
       } else {
          concatName+= "s3n://" + s3_bucket + "/" + fName + ",";
       }
    }
```